# MySQL after group by get value with preference of null

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have data set where i can use group by. I want preferably get null value if it is available (want to know if event is not finished)

example eventTable:

```
ID event finished
1 event1 2017-01-01
2 event2 NULL
3 event3 2017-05-18
4 event1 NULL
```

SQL:

```
SELECT event, max(finished) FROM eventTable group by event
```

gives unwanted result:

```
event1 2017-01-01
event2 NULL
event3 2017-05-18
```

result i want is (see NULL value at event1):

```
event1 NULL
event2 NULL
event3 2017-05-18
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional aggregation to check if there exist null then show null else show max of date

```
SELECT event, 
case when sum( finished is null) > 0
     then null else max(finished)
end as finished
FROM eventTable 
group by event
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/XNZ8282)

Comment: very nice solution, but I think you should write "sum(finished is NULL) >0"

Comment: @DanielE. Semantically both are same but yours is more readable

Comment: If finished is null more than once will your case work ?

Comment: It gets the value from that column, but not the entire corresponding row

Answer (score 1):

Use some date of future:

```
SELECT event, max(ifnull(finished, '2999-01-01')) 
FROM eventTable 
group by event ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MIN instead of MAX. Try this -

```
SELECT event
      ,min(finished) 
FROM eventTable 
GROUP BY event
```

Comment: min gives same result as max - seems this aggregations prefer not null values if available